# Why am I getting a "No attribute 'name' exists for the Match Locator" error when publishing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config-transform

I am so confused on this. I want to use the SQL Server on my desktop when I am developing and using the live SQL Server when I publish my project. I am playing with the transformation stuff in Visual Studio 2010.

I get the "No attribute 'name' exists for the Match Locator" when I try to publish my project.

My Web.config file contains:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=db" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=ASPState;Application Name=eGov" timeout="20" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" />
</system.web>
```

I am still testing it, so for now, my Web.Release.config file contains:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=db" 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
        sqlConnectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=ASPState;Application Name=app"
        timeout="20" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</system.web>
```

Anything I am seeing online is only confusing me more. Any help to get me up and running?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doh! The problem was in the `sessionState` section. It should be:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
        sqlConnectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=ASPState;Application Name=app"
        timeout="20" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="XPath(configuration/system.web/sessionState)" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 16):

`xdt:Locator="Match(name)` mean that system will match nodes to replace using **name** tag. If you don't have **name** attribute then it fails. You must have some unique attribute to use this type of transformation.

Answer (score 5):

Using "name" in Match(name) is for a typical config setting like the following. The key in this case is "name".

```
<add name="errorAddress" email="me@google.com" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```

If the key in your setting is something else, that is what you need to use:

```
<add token="UserToken" value="23jkl2klk2j3kja9d8f" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(token)"/>
```